# Quand utiliser « pareille » et quand « la même » ?

Tags: comparatifs

Pourquoi la phrase « Dans une pareille situation, tout est compliqué. » est-elle correcte ? Est-ce que je peux dire « Dans la même situation, tout est compliqué. » ?
Quelle est la différence entre « pareille » et « la même » ?

Comment: I couldn't explain why but `dans pareille situation` means `in such a situation`, and `dans la même situation` means `in the same situation`.

Answer (score 2):

1.

> (TLFi A. Qui présente une identité ou une ressemblance plus ou moins totale.
>   1. [Pour introd. une compar. implicite] Semblable (à une autre personne ou une autre chose) par l'aspect, la grandeur, la nature, la valeur ou tout autre point de vue considéré. Synon. identique, même, semblable, similaire.

On voit que « même » est un synonyme de « pareil » ; cependant l'usage veut que l'on n'utilise pas syntaxiquement cet adjectif de la même façon.

- Il veut la même voiture de sport.
- Il veut une voiture de sport pareille.

Lorsque l'on utilise « pareil » avant le nom, cet adjectif prend une signification légèrement différente, il ne signifie plus « ressemblance plus ou moins totale » mais « dont la sorte est la même ».

> (TLFi) C. [Avec une valeur dém.] De cette nature, de cette sorte.

- Dans une pareille situation tout est compliqué.

On pourrait dire à la place de cela « Dans une situation de cette sorte tout est compliqué. »; le mot « cette » nous rappelle ce que la définition dit : « avec une valeur démonstrative ».

Attention, l'emploi dans ce sens, « C », peut aussi être après le nom et alors une connotation d'emphase ou à nature de louange est ajoutée.

- Un pareil thé dans sa cuisine et elle bois du tilleul ! (*Le thé est vanté comme étant d'une remarquable qualité.*)
- Je n'ai jamais vu une voiture pareille ! (*surprise due au caractère extraordinaire de la voiture, louange*)
- Une voiture pareille et vous ne pouvez pas doubler sur une autoroute à quatre voies ? (*emphase*)
- Vous ne ferez jamais cent km en ville avec une voiture pareille ; avant longtemps vous allez être arrêté par la police. (*péjoratif*)
  *Dans le présent exemple « pareille » signifie « d'une sorte ou apparence aussi peu normale » (mauvais état, mauvais chargement, etc.*)

2.

« Dans la même situation, tout est compliqué. » ne se dit pas et il est difficile de dire pourquoi. On pourra trouver la formulation suivante correcte, par exemple.

- Quand cela lui arrive elle sait quoi faire, mais lui, dans la même situation, il ne sait jamais se débrouiller. (*Il faut comprendre bien sûr que « même situation » réfère à une situation comme celle dont on parle au début de la phrase mais  sans lui donner ce nom et qui est une situation où quelque chose arrive à la personne désignée par « elle ».*)

Ce qu'il semble que l'on puisse affirmer c'est que ce qui est dit après le terme caractérisé par « pareil » ne peut pas le concerner mais doit être à propos de quelque chose ou de quelqu'un qui s'y rapporte. Cela est une question de logique : puisque vous parlez de la même chose vous n'avez pas besoin  pour la caractériser de dire que c'est la même, mais pour parler de ce qui peut aussi arriver en rapport avec une répétition de cette chose dans d'autres circonstances, donc, dit un peu différemment, en rapport avec la même chose, il n'y a pas de problème.